# User information made available to merchants by paypal

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

I would like to know if paypal makes the below information available to merchants who use paypal's payment gateway to process payments:

1. Email Address of the user.
2. Full name of the user as registered with paypal.
3. Billing Address of the user as registered with paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the product you're using, but I'm going to assume you're using Express Checkout.

1. Yes, this is included in IPN data as well as the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and GetTransactiondetails API response.
2. Yes, this is included in IPN data as well as the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and GetTransactiondetails API response.
3. No, unless you're a very large merchant and have a real business need for this, then it will be available in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API response.